# Mongodb query behaves differently in various platforms

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I'm running this query agains the same db in various environments:

```
        $routes = array(); //assume is array of routes
        $regex_1 = new MongoRegex("/(pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4)/");
        $regex_2 = new MongoRegex("/(pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4|pattern5|pattern6)/");

        foreach ($routes as $route) {
            $where["name"] = $route["name"];
            if (preg_match('/route1/', $routeName)) {
                $where["url"] = array("\$not" => $regex_1);
            } elseif (preg_match('/route2/', $routeName)) {
                $where["url"] = array("\$not" => $regex_2);
            }

            $count = $col->count($where);
```

It all works fine on my local environment, however, once I put the code on the QA server it fails without any kind of error or log. I've been researching this for a couple of days now and I have no idea what to do anymore. I tried restructuring the query in multiple ways, nothing worked.

I checked the php modules versions just to be sure and they're all the same.

One thing I did notice was that the queries run fine in all environments when the patterns are short (less than 5 or 6 matches) it all seems to work.

So I guess the question is: What's wrong here? is it the code? configuration? php module? mongo itself?...

Hope this makes sense. Cheers!